# Завести Jupyter Notebook через terminator

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, jupyter-notebook

terminator - удобный многооконный терминал для Linux (у меня Ubuntu 16). Но на ввод jupyter notebook отвечает "команда на найдена". 
Где и что исправить?

Comment: а не в terminator у вас работает? Укажите явно shell. К примеру, zsh может хэшировать директории из PATH (новые команды не видны сразу).

Comment: bash работает вполне корректно  и вообще и ipython заводит

Comment: означает ли фраза: *"bash работает вполне корректно"*, что ввод `jupyter notebook` в bash запускает сервер? Что `type jupyter` показывает?

Comment: Так и есть - " ввод jupyter notebook в bash запускает сервер". Где посмотреть "type jupyter" не понимаю, "/ML/PCA.ipynb" - это?

Comment: В командной строке введите `type jupyter`. Чему $SHELL у вас равно?

Comment: Проблема отвалилась сама, также непонятно как и взялась - jupyter завёлся из терминатора.

Comment: И вот 2й раз за полгода та же история. Только на этот раз JN не заводится даже из bash. Пишет "jupyter: команда не найдена".  В прошлый раз проблема непонятно откуда взялась и так же непонятно сама собой отвалилась. Но тогда не заводилось только через terminator, теперь совсем никак.

Comment: сложно без дополнительной информации: как у вас jupyter установлен (в virtualenv, используете ли conda), сколько у вас python версий стоит (`type python`, `type jupyter`), активно ли virtualenv, что в `$PATH`.

Comment: Прописал в .bashrc путь, всё заработало. Открытым остаётся вопрос, как путь, прописанный ранее, соскочил?.....